# ClassNotFoundException when install the application (AdMob)

Tags: admob, classnotfoundexception

I have the next log when install my app

> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
> >     com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver
> >     in loader
> >     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.tarsoft.bandroidcalls-1.apk]
> >     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1894)
> >     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:123)
> >     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
> >     at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
> >     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
> >     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> >     Method) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> >     at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
> >     at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
> >     at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> >     Method) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver
> >     in loader
> >     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.tarsoft.bandroidcalls-1.apk]
> >     at
> >     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
> >     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
> >     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
> >     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1885)

Someone know what is the problem with admob?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in your AndroidManifest.xml, with the new AdMob sdk you need to change com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver to com.google.ads.InstallReceiver.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
It means that you have no required class in your classpath.

Try to use http://code.google.com/intl/pl/mobile/afma_ads/docs/android/doubleclick/#afma-gettingstarted instead of your library.